# iText7 fails to render dropdown as a forms fillable field in in C# (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I am trying to create an fillable pdf form using iText7 (in C# .Net framework) by passing an HTML using the [itext7.pdfhtml library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/).  iText is successful in generating most of the fillable fields from the html except the dropdown.

The dropdown field appears to be read-only and chooses the first value as the default. I cannot click on it for selection. Please see the attached image from the pdf.

```cs
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(dest);
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfWriter);

converterProperties.SetCreateAcroForm(true);

//For setting the PAGE SIZE
pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(PageSize.A3));

iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm form = iText.Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
Document document = HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(htmlString, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
document.Close();
```

[image: rendered editable pdf image]

Comment: Are you referring to [this nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/)?

Comment: yes, that is the package along with itext7

Comment: Hi, can you attach the original HTML to reproduce the problem?